# Rails run ImageUploader before assign virtual attributes from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to apply Jcrop in my Rails app, the frontend part works fine, no need to post the code here. The problem is when I try to CREATE. Rails for some reason runs the code from ThumbnailUploader before assigning the virtual attributes that I've created.

From what I've checked, this line executes the ThumbnailUploader code:

```
@thumbnail = Thumbnail.new(thumbnail_params)
```

**thumbnail_params** has all the coordinates ok, I checked, but it doesn't set the variables to crop in the ThumbnailUploader for some reason that I don't have idea.

When I UPDATE it works 100% as expected. I'm gonna paste my **ThumbnailController**, my **Thumbnail Model** and my **ThumbnailUploader** so you guys can check you:

- Rails -v: 4.1.6
- Ruby -v: 2.1.3

**Gems**:

- gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
- gem 'carrierwave'
- gem 'fog'
- gem 'carrierwave_direct'

**ThumbnailController**:

```
class ThumbnailsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_thumbnail, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /thumbnails
  # GET /thumbnails.json
  def index
    @thumbnails = Thumbnail.all
  end

  # GET /thumbnails/1
  # GET /thumbnails/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /thumbnails/new
  def new
    @thumbnail = Thumbnail.new           
  end  

  # POST /thumbnails
  # POST /thumbnails.json
  def create    
    @thumbnail = Thumbnail.new(thumbnail_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @thumbnail.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @thumbnail }        
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @thumbnail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /thumbnails/1
  # PATCH/PUT /thumbnails/1.json
  def update    
    @thumbnail.crop_x = thumbnail_params[:crop_x]
    @thumbnail.crop_y = thumbnail_params[:crop_y]
    @thumbnail.crop_w = thumbnail_params[:crop_w]
    @thumbnail.crop_h = thumbnail_params[:crop_h]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @thumbnail.update(thumbnail_params)
        Post.cached_find(@thumbnail.post.id).thumbnail.touch
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thumbnail was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @thumbnail }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @thumbnail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_thumbnail
      @thumbnail = Thumbnail.find(params[:id])          
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def thumbnail_params
      params.require(:thumbnail).permit(:image, :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h)
    end
  end
```

**Thumbnail.rb:**

```
class Thumbnail < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  belongs_to :post
  mount_uploader :image, ThumbnailUploader
end
```

**ThumbnailUploader:**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ThumbnailUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end
  # 
  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  process :crop

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.nil?  
      ###   WHERE MY PROBLEM LIVES ####
      #### !!!!! model.crop_x IS ALWAYS NIL WHEN TRYING TO CREATE !!!! #####       
      resize_to_fill(256, 256)    
      convert('jpg')
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.crop!(0, 10, 256, 238)
      end
    else
      #### THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GET, I GET HERE WHEN UPDATE ####
      resize_to_fill(800, 440)
      convert('jpg')
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
      resize_to_fill(256, 238)
    end
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
    # %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  def filename
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.jpg' if original_filename
  end

end
```

And here's my form. The **output** tag is where the image is shown after the user select the image to upload so he can chose where he wants to crop:

```
  <output id="list"></output>
  <br />
  <br />

  <% %w[x y w h].each do |att| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "crop_#{att}" %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.file_field :image, required: true, class: 'form-control' %></p>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-success btn-block disabled', id: 'thumbnail-send' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I followed this code from [Ryan Bates RailsCast #182(Revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised)

Sorry if I'm missing something, it's very late here and I googling this for many hours with no results. Hope I have some help here.

Note:
I already tried to do the same thing that I did at Update action, it doesn't work because rails runs the:

```
@thumbnail = Thumbnail.new(thumbnail_params)
```

before. And trying to add that code before this line it will throw an error saying that crop_x doesn't exists.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
def create         
    @thumbnail = Thumbnail.new(      
      crop_x: thumbnail_params[:crop_x],
      crop_y: thumbnail_params[:crop_y],
      crop_w: thumbnail_params[:crop_w],
      crop_h: thumbnail_params[:crop_h],
      image: thumbnail_params[:image]
      )    
...
```

Did the trick.
The problem was the order of the hash. :image was the 1st element of the hash, so Rails read and executed it before even setting the attr_accessors that I've created.

So be careful, Rails is doing this weird thing when it should first set everything up before trying to upload.